# Force exerted by ideal spring in our hand

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, spring

Suppose we have an ideal spring. We push the spring with our hand in the $x$ direction (so we don't need to take account gravity) exerting a force $-F_{h}$. From Newton's third law the spring exert to our hand  a force $F_h$. Also the spring at some point where it is extended it will exert a force according to Hooke's law $F_H$. If we measured the force that is applied in our hand will we measure $F_T=F_h + F_H$?

Answer (score 2):

Newton's third law doesn't *create* a reactionary force which is the vector opposite of the force you apply. Rather, it describes a property of forces in nature that already exist, this is to say that it describes a relationship between forces that arise out of some dynamic causes of their own.

Now, if you apply a force $-F_h$ on the spring and the spring applies a total force $F_h+F_H$ on you then Newton's third law would be violated. So, the total force that the spring applies on you must be $F_h$. However, Newton's third law doesn't actually cause any forces to be generated (unlike, say, the gravitational law of Newton which truly is a description of the dynamic cause of the force of gravity). Rather, as I said, it describes a relationship between forces that arise out of some dynamic causes of their own. This means that this force $F_h$ that the spring would apply on your hand has to arise from some mechanical origin. And what would that origin be? It'd precisely be Hooke's law as you suspect. So, there wouldn't be an additional force due to Hooke's law, but rather, the force generated according to Hooke's law, say $F_H$, would itself be $F_h$.

In other words, this means that Newton's third law tells us that the elongation/compression of the spring when you apply a force $-F_h$ on it will be such that the force that the spring applies back on you (due to Hooke's law) would be of value $F_h$.

Comment: Why it violates third law? The total force on spring is $F_{net}=-(F_h + F_H)$ If the spring exert a force in another object due to compression/elongation then from 3rd law a force should be exerted on it.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal spring is an artifact to concentrate all the mass of a real spring at the point where the force is applied. So the net force on this mass will change depending on the balance of applied forces and spring deflection.

If an external force $-F_h$ is applied to the system, the reaction will be $F_h$.

The mass in the spring will accelerate until the displacement $x = \frac {F_h}{k}$ is reached, when the net force on it $F_n = 0$.

From this point, $F_n > 0$, the speed decreases until changes direction. If the applied force doesn't change, the system keeps oscillating.

But the reaction force from the mass to the hand is $F_h$ all the time.

An ideal spring without mass is like a conductor where a current doesn't generate a magnetic field. It can't be.

Comment: The total force on our hand therefore is the force from reaction (of the force we apply to the spring) and the force from the spring right?

Comment: If we keep applying the same force the reaction also doesn't change. If we "feel" anytime a stronger force, it is an indication that we increased our force over the system.